# Why AsyncStorage getItem is returning null?

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

```
export const USER_KEY = "isLoggedIn";

export const phoneVerified = () => AsyncStorage.setItem(USER_KEY, 1);
export const userInfoVerified = () => AsyncStorage.setItem(USER_KEY, 2);
```

I have used the above functions to store the value and the below one to get the value.

```
export const isSignedIn = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem(USER_KEY)
      .then(res => {
          console.log("from isSignedIn : "+res); //res is showing null.
        if (res !== null) {
          resolve(res);
        } else {
          resolve(0);
        }
      })
      .catch(err => reject(err));
  });
};
```

Why this always returns null? I was trying async/await but still getting null. I think somehow the data is not storing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm afraid you can only store strings. Please refer to this [React Native AsyncStorage storing values other than strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35596187/react-native-asyncstorage-storing-values-other-than-strings) and this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html#setitem

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As answered by @Vishu Bhardwaj AsyncStorage accepts only string. So you can use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with this stupid problem for almost one week, no other way that is suggested in all communities worked for me, but then I found something that is built of react-native which its setState() callback function: https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296.
so the only way that I guarantee that it's the only secure way so far is this that u use the setState() function in your promise and everything that you need to run, put them on a function and call it for the setState() callback function , this is only way you can make sure yourself that you neither get null nor never calling the function . Here I'm going to provide an example of it which this.tokeToServer() is my function which it's used as a callback function.

```
try {
      AsyncStorage.getItem('firebase_token',(err,item) => {
        if (item) {
          this.setState({
            firebase_token: item,
          }),this.tokenToServer();
        }
      });
      } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error retrieving data" + error);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As presented by friend Abdu4, I had the same problem for 4 days and searching for different sites and forums. Attempts with async/await and others, even though you should use these options, the one you completed and really worked was to assign the value through setState by callback

```
try {
        AsyncStorage.getItem('TOKEN_KEY',(err,item) => {
            if (item) {
                setToken({
                    Token: item,
                });
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error retrieving data" + error);
    }
```